# PHP - Multidimensional Array Sum values if key matches

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and would like to "summarize/reduce" it so all the values that match a key get added up and the rest stay as they're:

```
$payments = [
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 50],
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 85],
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 4, 'amount' => 14],
];
```

Expected Result:

```
$payments = [
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 135],
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 4, 'amount' => 14],
 ];
```

I know i can achieve this using a loop, just wondering if there's a better way of doing it:

```
$output = [];
foreach($payments as $value) {
    if(!array_key_exists($value['vendorId', $output))
        $output[$value['vendorId'] = [
          'bookingId' => $value['bookingId'], 
          'vendorId' => $value['vendorId'], 
          'amount' => $value['amount']
        ];
    else
        $output[$value['vendorId']['amount'] += $value['amount'];
}
$payments = array_values($output);
```

In this example 'bookingId' always remains the same, im including it in the array cause i'll then use the result array to insert in DB

Comment: Is that array coming directly from the database? If so, can you run a query to get your summary?

Comment: You are missing the ending bracket `]` on your array selections. e.g `$value['vendorId',`, `$output[$value['vendorId']['amount']`

Comment: @Qirel its coming from js

Comment: Here another solution http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c23d35082a03d56522f38e9b6393585fa70ad31

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve pretty same result with [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$payments = [
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 50],
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 85],
  ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 4, 'amount' => 14],
];

$result = array_reduce(
    $payments,
    function(array $carry, array $payment): array {
        $prev = $carry[$payment['vendorId']]['amount'] ?? 0;
        $carry[$payment['vendorId']] = $payment;
        $carry[$payment['vendorId']]['amount'] += $prev;
        
        return $carry;
    },
    []
);

var_dump(array_values($result));
```

**Edit:**
Forgot to add initial array, fixed, now should work

Answer (score 1):

That looks solid to me, although you've got a syntax error in the loop, and you can reduce the code in the `if` statement quite a bit, you're working too hard there.

```
<?php
$payments = [
    ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 50],
    ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 85],
    ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 4, 'amount' => 14],
];

$expected = [
    ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 3, 'amount' => 135],
    ['bookingId' => 1, 'vendorId' => 4, 'amount' => 14],
];

$output = [];
foreach ($payments as $value)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($value['vendorId'], $output))
    {
        $output[$value['vendorId']] = $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $output[$value['vendorId']]['amount'] += $value['amount'];
    }
}

$payments = array_values($output);

assert($payments == $expected, 'Output should match expected results');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper array like this

```
$aHelper = [];
foreach($payments as $payment) {
    $bookingId = $payment['bookingId'];
    $vendorId = $payment['vendorId'];
    $amount = $payment['amount'];
    if (!isset($aHelper[ $bookingId ][ $vendorId ])) {
        $aHelper[ $bookingId ][ $vendorId ] = 0;
    }
    $aHelper[ $bookingId ][ $vendorId ] += $amount;
}
```